# Probability and Venn Diagrams

Tags: probability

The question in concern asks, "$136$ people were asked if they liked Math, Science, or Social Studies. They all liked at least one.

$40$ like Math

$17$ like Math and Science

$40$ like Science

$8$ like Science and Social Studies

$32$ like Social Studies

$11$ like Math and Social Studies

$6$ like all three subjects."

My question is that although it says $136$ people were surveyed, the results that were gathered afterwards add up to $154$. Where are the extra $18$ people coming from exactly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A single person can have more than one interest.

Comment: To add to @PrasunBiswas comment, one person can be counted in "like Math", "like Math and Science" at the same time, for example.

Comment: @TonyS.F. The probability of it all would still be counted over 136 still right? So if I was asked, for example, what's the probability of someone not liking Science, it would counted as 83/136?

Comment: There are $136 - 40 = 96$ people who do not like Science, but you are correct that the denominator should be $136$.  The $40$ people who like Science include those who like both Science and another subject.

Comment: Actually, something is off about these numbers.  If you apply the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), you will find that the number who like at least one of these subjects is less than $136$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I am relooking at it, following the strategy of Bram below and I am also finding that the numbers will result to be less than 136.

Comment: Oh! Right, I am just now seeing the 'They all liked at least one' ...  OK, then something is definitely off here!

Comment: Based on these numbers, $40 + 40 + 32 - 17 - 8 - 11 + 6 = 82$ of the $136$ people surveyed liked at least one subject, contrary to the claim that each person liked at least one subject.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Using my Venn Diagram, those are the same numbers I got. A whole 54 people weren't accounted for, but the question says they were...

Comment: Indeed,  The data is inconsistent.  By the way.  What exactly *is* the problem this data is provided for?  What were you actually asked to find?

Comment: So maybe these *are* real life numbers! :)

Comment: @Bram28 So what do I do in the case of real life numbers?

Comment: @user55614 First you should ask what this '$40$ like math' means. Second, ask for a recount!

Answer (score 4):

If I were given these numbers in real life I would, like you, interpret the claim that '$40$ like Math' as '40 like Math but not Science and also not social science', given that it has separate numbers for all kinds of combination of liking subject areas. So, I can understand your confusion!

But, given as that does indeed add up to more than $136$, probably the claim means that '40 like math  .... and possibly science or social science as well'

Thus, for example, the $17$ people that like Math and Science are part of the $40$ people that like Math.

As such, you can actually use a Venn diagram to figure out exactly how many people are in each of the different regions of that diagram. For example, given that $6$ people like all three subjects, and given that $17$ people like both Math and Science, we can infer that $17-6=11$ people like Math and Science but not Social Science.

In fact, given that there will be quite a bit of overlap between the different subject areas, you'll probably get quite a few people *less* than $136$ that likes any subject at all: probably quite a few don't like any of the three subjects! Again, draw a Venn diagram, and you can work out all the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

What you were probably missing is that one person *can* like more than one subject.

Let me give you a more simple example, with $2$ subjects.

> $10$ people like math, $20$ like science, and $8$ like both.

First, jump to $8$ like both.

There are $10-8=2$ people who like math only.

There are $20-8=12$ people who like science only.

Now, add $8$ into your counting - the $8$ people who like both math and science.

So, there are $2+12+8=22$ people in total.

Implement this same logic, this time for $3$ subjects, and start by drawing a Venn Diagram!

Hint: Start from in to out (start from excluding people who like all $3$ subjects and counting them *all the way* at the end).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/971833)

Comment: @XanderHenderson I hope it is good now.

Answer (score 0):

It is a question on Venn diagrams and the data provided contains intersections. Clearly the intent is that the sets, M,S,T (for **M**aths, **S**cience, and Social S**t**udies):
$$\begin{split}n(\Omega)&=136\\n(M)&=40\\ n(M\cap S)&=17\\n(S)&=40\\n(S\cap T)&=8\\ n(T)&=32\\n(M\cap T)&=11\\ n(M\cap S\cap T)&=6\end{split}$$

Now, were you *told* that everbody liked at least one, or were you asked to find *how many* liked at least one?  Because the data would seem to state, by the principle of inclusion and exclusion, that

$$n(M\cup S\cup T)~{=n(M)+n(S)+n(T)-n(M\cap S)-n(M\cap T)-n(S\cap T)+n(M\cap S\cap T)\\\ll 136}$$

Comment: What the problem gave me was the information I listed originally above, and then it asked probability questions afterwards, i.e., "What is the probability that someone likes Science but not Math?" However, because it has been proven to be less than 136 people now that we have seen, what number would I use to calculate probability? 82 or 136?